# blank list error when taking data from web site

Tags: python-2.7

I have a problem on API. Its turns to me empty list

I tried to search browser but none is my answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib import re

site = "http://www.hurriyet.com.tr" 
regex = "<span class='news-title'>(.+?)</span>" 
comp = re.compile(regex) 
print(comp) print(regex) 
htmlkod = urllib.urlopen(site).read() 
titles = re.findall(regex, htmlkod) 
print(titles) 
i=1 
for title in titles:
        print str(i), title.decode("iso8859-9")
        print(title)
        i+=1
```

I Expect the its turn to me news titles but its turn me "[]" empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use BeautifulSoup instead of regex like :

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
site = "http://www.hurriyet.com.tr"
openurl = urlopen(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(openurl, "html.parser")
getTitle = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'news-title'})

for title in getTitle:
    print title.text
```

Comment: Hocam 
"from urllib import urlopen"
unutmuşuz cevap için çok teşekkürler.